# About the Taylor polynomial of the antiderivative of a function

Tags: taylor-expansion

If $P_{n, g} (x)$ denotes the $n$-order Taylor polynomial of a function $g$ around $x = a$, and if $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ ($f \in C_{\mathbb{R}}^\infty$).

Does  $P_{n+1, F} (x) = \int_{a}^{x}P_{n,f} (x)dx$ ?
I think the statement is true, but I'm stuck trying to show it.

The LHS should be:
$$ P_{n+1, F}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \frac{F^{(k)(} (a)}{k!} (x-a)^k$$

But I get the following in the RHS:

$$ \int_{a}^{x} P_{n, f} (x) dx = \int_{a}^{x} (\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(k)} (a)}{k!} (x-a)^k )dx 
= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{(k+1)! } (x-a)^{(k+1)} \\
\int_{a}^{x} P_{n, f} (x) dx= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{F^{(k+1)}(a)}{(k+1)! } (x-a)^{(k+1)} = 
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{F^{(k)}(a)}{(k)! } (x-a)^{(k)}\\
\int_{a}^{x} P_{n, f} (x) dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \frac{F^{(k)}(a)}{(k)! } (x-a)^{(k)} - F(a)$$

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is
$$
P_{n+1, F} (x) =  F(a) + \int_{a}^{x}P_{n,f} (t) \, dt
$$
which is what you got in the second calculation. It satisfies $P_{n+1, F} (a) = F(a)$ and
$$
P_{n+1, F}^{(k)} (a) = P_{n,f}^{(k-1)}(a) = f^{(k-1)}(a) = F^{(k)}(a)
$$
for $1 \le k \le n+1$.

It is correct that $P_{n+1, F}$ is an antiderivative of $P_{n,f}$, but the constant of integration must be chosen such that $P_{n+1, F} (a) = F(a)$.